# Access Form refusing to change focus from one text input to another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got a basic login form in Microsoft Access, where the VBA script I have to clear all Text Box' will not change the focus from one text box to another. The popup I get as you may have assumed is Run-time error '2110'. Even after multiple debugging steps and making sure that they're both enabled and visible, the script simply won't work as intended.

Here's my code:

```vb
1 | Private Sub Form_load()
2 |     If Me.FirstInput.Visible = False Then
3 |         Me.FirstInput.Visible = True
4 |     End If
5 |     If Me.LastInput.Visible = False Then
6 |         Me.LastInput.Visible = True
7 |     End If
8 |     If Me.ErrorTxt.Visible = True Then
9 |         Me.ErrorTxt.Visible = False
10|     End If
11|     Me.FirstInput.SetFocus
12|     Me.FirstInput.Text = ""
13|     Me.LastInput.SetFocus
14|     Me.LastInput.Text = ""
15|     Me.FirstInput.SetFocus
16|     Me.LastInput.Visible = False
17| End Sub
```

The error is where I'm changing the focus to "LastInput" on line 13. If someone could give me some guidance onto how I could fix this or if you need any more information, then please let me know.

Edit: Just for the people wondering if either of my Text Box' have their Enabled or Locked properties set incorrectly:
[image: Proof of enabled and locked]

Comment: Is that "LastInput" control Visible, Enabled, not Blocked? is it a label, which by definition cannot receive the focus? Nothing than 'runt-time error '2110' is shown in the error message? I cannot reproduce this error to better understand what it means...

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, thank you for your reply. Both the FirstInput and LastInput Text Box' have their Enabled, Visible properties set to Yes. They both have Labels attached too. Neither are locked either, which is what I'm assuming you mean by Blocked.

Comment: Is there an event code running when `Me.FirstInput.Text = ""` is run? Could it be that blocking the focus from moving? Some validation code maybe?

Comment: There is validation code, however it isn't ran as far as I'm aware. There are 3 events which call the sub program, when the login button is clicked, when the FirstInput captures the Enter key, and when the LastInput captures the Enter key. Could this have been ran when changing the text?

Comment: It may or may not solve the problem, but please regard some point on this: (1) You don't need to check if the control is visible, just setting it to `.visible=True` is sufficient. If it was already visible, no harm is done. (2) You may avoid to set the focus if you use the `.value` attribute to empty the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've managed to solve the issue at hand, as per a chat between me and @wakgtech. We decided between ourselves that instead of having to set the focus to change the `text` property of the object, that it would be better to scrap using the `.SetFocus` method all together and instead use the `value` property.

However now what I have discovered is that the Text Box' onEnter event was being called when I changed the value of the elements in question. So I turned around and ended up deleting them regardless.

The three times that the 'validation' code was being called, was when the attempt sign in button was clicked and if the enter key was pressed in either of the text box'. Where the values of the text box' where empty anyways, causing the error message element to become visible through that.

I thank everyone in this thread for your support, if you have any further questions onto how it was solved then please let me know in a comment. As of now, as I can't close it myself, I'm declaring my question answered/closed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The way you use the visible property, I guess that you want to force the user to enter the FirstName first, and I also guess that you have an `AfterUpdate` event procedure to hide the `LastInput` textbox if no reasonable firstname was entered...

Unfortunately, changing the value of the `Text` property is like typing the value into the textbox, meaning that the `AfterUpdate` event is fired which would hide the `LastInput` textbox so it can't get the focus.

I suggest to change the code a bit and use the `Value` property (which is the default property) to empty both textboxes:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    FirstInput.Visible = True
    LastInput.Visible = False
    ErrorTxt.Visible = False

    FirstInput = Null
    LastInput = Null

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, now I have a different problem. I have no run-time error as such, however a logical error to which I don't really understand with all of the events with Input Box'. Now when the form loads, both the first input and last input fields are displayed, meaning that the validation code is being ran? But also that whenever I try and click on a text box, it'll say that I'm signed in for some reason? However at this stage I don't actually have any full validation for the first name and last name within the table of records.

Comment: We neither know your "validation code" nor what event causes it to run. Do you need to validate the blank textboxes when the form loads?

Answer (score 0):

Check your control's "Enabled" property. I bet it is set to False.

Comment: Nope, they're both set to Yes.

Comment: Did you check them one at a time? you can not check the enabled property on two objects at the same time. Access will grab the setting for the first one and display it.

Comment: I did, however they both have the same value after checking individually. Thank you for telling me that though, didn't know that at all. I was completely under the impression that the field would be blank if the values across the objects in selection are different. The more you know I guess

Comment: OK, lets try this, Instead of setting the text property, set the VALUE property. That negates the use of .SetFocus altogether.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply @wakgtech. I've changed everything to value assuming that it holds the same function. I've also come to realise that when I do that, it also ends up running the validation function that I mentioned above, so the Error Text element that I have ends up appearing visible even when I set to be invisible at the very end of the form load sub program.

Comment: Correct, because even though you set it to be invisible on load, when you change the VALUE property that fires the event again. I must say I am curious abut this validation function. what is it checking for? could you post it? There may be other ways of doing this (there always is!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202804/discussion-between-ben-foster04-and-wakgtech).

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the form explicitly as in `Form!Form1.LastInput.SetFocus` 
 I know it seems silly but I have noticed in my own personal experience that I have encountered hiccups within access like you have mentioned and an explicit reference will clear it up.